# Choose random integer in a range bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, random

I know there are another questions about random in a range but none of their answers accomplishes what I am trying to do. Actually they have the same error I have. I wrote this simple function to generate random with range.

```
Random m_random = new Random();
...
public int RandomWithRange(int min, int max) {
    return m_random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

If range is bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE, it throws an IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive. I know it overflows and turn to a negative number. My question is how to handle that?

Example ranges;

- [0, Integer.MAX_VALUE]
- [Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE]
- [-100, Integer.MAX_VALUE]

Note: min and max must be inclusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that `(max - min)` overflows and gives you a negative value.

You can use a `long` instead.

```
public int randomWithRange(int min, int max) {
    return (int) ((m_random.nextLong() & Long.MAX_VALUE) % (1L + max - min)) + min;
}
```

Comment: I think that is the best solution. I'll delete my answer

Comment: This doesn't give a correct uniform distribution.  (Effective Java item 47 actually mentions this incorrect approach specifically.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman This is better than nextInt(int) (but more expensive) What did you have in mind?

Comment: If you look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) of `Random.nextInt`, it discusses how you have to use a loop, rejecting values that would result in an incorrect distribution.  (I was hoping that that technique could be borrowed somehow.)

Comment: The reason for the incorrect distribution is as follows: suppose we were working with four-bit numbers, `max` were 2, and `min` were 0.  But there are four 4-bit values that are `0` mod `3`, but only three values that are `1` mod `3`, and three values that are `2` mod `3`.  So `0` is actually 33% more likely than `1` or `2` in this case.  The problem occurs (for any number of bits) whenever `max - min + 1` isn't a power of two.

Comment: It has to do this because it grabs 31 bits at a time which can be close to the number of bits in the range. using nextLong() takes 63 bits which will never be close to the range.  Even if the range is 32 bit there can be 1 in 2^31 bias. But given Random only uses a 48-bit seed, this is far greater cause of bias.

Comment: By "the range is 32 bit" what do you mean?  I'm not convinced by this argument.  In any event, `Random.nextInt(int)` claims in its documentation that "If it were a perfect source of randomly chosen bits, then the algorithm shown would choose int values from the stated range with perfect uniformity," which makes me feel better about using its approach.

Comment: The range is less than 2^32 so there is less than a one in 2^(63-32) chance of a bias. However, using a seed of 48-bit means there is likely to a one in 2^16 bias.

Comment: Hmmmmkay.  I was wondering if it was something along those lines.  I suppose that that's tolerable, given that that can at most affect one possible value.  My downvote is now an upvote.

Comment: If you use SecureRandom you could use the code from nextInt with nextLong instead but I doubt the extra complexity is needed here. Upvoted your quibble. ;)

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov You are right, it needs an extra ( ), fixed it http://ideone.com/oe7V59

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use int in this case. You need to go with [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). The following constructor does what you want (need some tweaking for your needs of course):

```
BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd)
```

> Constructs a randomly generated BigInteger, uniformly distributed over
>   the range 0 to (2numBits - 1), inclusive.

Comment: There's a lot of genuinely nontrivial implementation detail missing here.  Even once you've determined the right number of bits (which isn't obvious), you also have to check that the result remains in range, and repeat if it isn't, to get a correct uniform distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered getting a random double and then casting back to int

```
return (int)(m_random.nextDouble() * ((double)max - (double)min) + min);
```

Comment: Are you sure this works?  It seems to me that `(max - min)` is going to give you an integer overflow; so the result won't be what you expect.

Comment: You can cast min and max to doubles to avoid the overflow. If we consider the edge case of INT_MAX - INT_MIN you get about 2*INT_MAX if that then gets multiplied with 1 from the prng you still end by adding(subtracting) INT_MIN to it after the cast. So you could simply move the + min into the cast to make sure that you don't overflow.

Comment: I agree that you can do that.  Perhaps you could edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: nextDouble() is [0.0, 1.0), so even if I choose max as Integer.MAX_VALUE, there is no possibility to return it. Sorry if i mislead, question updated.

Answer (score 0):

The most "dumb but definitely correct" solution I can think of:

```
if (max - min + 1 > 0) // no overflow
  return delta + random.nextInt(max - min + 1);
else {
  int result;
  do {
    result = random.nextInt();
  } while (result < min || result > max);
  // finishes in <= 2 iterations on average
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This sounds reasonable. Does its "dumbness" arise from its continually choosing nextInt() from the full set of 2^32? How might we augment this approach to narrow the choices on each random choice to increase the likelihood of falling between min and max, while maintaining the uniformity of the distribution?