# Random integers - Both positive and negative

Tags: java, random, integer

I'd like to know how I could get a random integer between Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE. I did try this:

```
int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

Random rand = new Random();
StartVärde =  rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

Please note that I've imported java.util.Random and "StartVärde" is just a variable I've created. Now the code above gives the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:265)
at Räknare.<init>(Räknare.java:28)
at Räknare_Main.main(Räknare_Main.java:5)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choose random integer in a range bigger than Integer.MAX\_VALUE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773617/choose-random-integer-in-a-range-bigger-than-integer-max-value)

Comment: See answers below.  Besides, the reason is, that max-min does not fit into an integer and thus can't be passed to nextInt.  Use nextLong() if you want something with larger range.

Comment: Also, you could run into problems with special characters in variable names. If I were you, I'd rename `StartVärde` to `startVaerde` (lowercase due to Java naming conventions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the javadoc for [`Random.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29)

> Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value from
>   this random number generator's sequence. The general contract of
>   nextInt is that one int value is pseudorandomly generated and
>   returned. All 2<sup>32</sup> possible int values are produced with
>   (approximately) equal probability.

So, if you use `Random.nextInt()` is will return a value between `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `rand.nextInt()` instead. It will return a random `int` of 32 bits. Since in Java `int` are interpreted as signed, you will get both positive and negative values.

**More info :**

- [Random.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

From the Java docs for [nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) of java.util.Random:

```
All 2^32 possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.
```

You may want to try

```
StartVärde =  rand.nextInt();
```

By default, it would produce positive and negative random numbers.

Comment: No, you need `Random.nextInt()` **not** `Random.nextInt(int n)`.